# Possible to list categories on Main Page?

Tags: mediawiki

I would like to put all the categories at the bottom of the Main Page in a more compact way than what `Special:Categories` does.

On [this](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category%3aList_extensions) page are pages listed in a very nice way with bold letters.

Can the same be done with categories instead of pages?

Comment: @toomanyairmiles, that's what the tag is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a bunch of MediaWiki extensions that provide such features.  A few you may want to take a look at include:

- [CategoryTree](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aCategoryTree): A simple extension that, like the name suggests, provides a way to include an expandable category tree on a wiki page.
- [DynamicPageList](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aDynamicPageList_%28Wikimedia%29): An extremely versatile extension that can be used to list pages according to various criteria, including membership in a category.